# Why Application Penetration Testing is required?

Tags: penetration-test

I've developed application for receiving payments on my shop site. However, my clients are asking and forcing to complete a penetration testing. 
Why there is need of penetration testing, when I already testing and audited my code.

Comment: What exactly did you test and how did you audit your code? Generally, developers/programmers get a pretty biased view on their own work and may overlook issues that are obvious to security professionals.

Comment: I've source code audit from a security expert.

Comment: The security testing of your code it's just one part of the equation.

Answer (score 6):

> Why there is need of penetration testing, when I already testing and audited my code.

It's the same reason why even code written by highly experienced developers should undergo peer review. *You* wrote the code so you might not be able to see the issues with it. It's very likely that you are too familiar with your own code to see any problems in it. There might even be ego issues getting in the way where you find it difficult to be objectively critical about the stuff you produce.

With security reviews, there is the additional issue that most developers simply do not have the security knowledge necessary to ensure that the application is vulnerability-free.